# Progress bar with image blocks

Tags: css

I am trying to create a grogress bar with with blocks that display the progress as show below. The width of the progress bar itself is at 768px and each block is about 24px (meaning at 100% there are 32 blocks).

While I have the basics of the progress bar in place, is there a way I can accurately display the progress with the blocks?

[image: Progress bar with blocks]

Any ideas, tips and suggestions would be of help...

Thanks

Comment: 100/32 = 3.125% per block. Total / 3.125 will equal the amount per block. What do you mean?

Comment: This is the problem I am facing.. I have calculated those values, but in the current app, the percentage is return as rounded numbers.  If I round down to 3%, the progress bar is not filled up.

Comment: Usually you round the value, 1.4 = 1%, 1.5 = 2%. With these kind of indicators there are no "precise" way of doing it, even integer based indicators are not exactly precise. It will show 0% until you reach 1.562 units.

Comment: Another solution is to "round up". 0.001 = 1%, but then you would be stuck on 100% for up to 1% of the time, compared with normal rounding which would only be stuck on 100% for 0.5% of the total time.